# Undo command in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would want to know if there is a sort of "`undo`" command in Minecraft (no mods) that undo one action at the time. For example, the player pressed a button that started a huge redstone system or he detonated one TNT that detonated other TNTs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, there is no built-in undo system.

However, if you are prepared for it, you can use the [`/clone`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#clone) command. You'll want to clone the part of the map (periodically) you are working on to another, far away area. Then, if you want to "undo" this, simply reverse this cycle, and clone the "backup" area into the "work" area.

Tip: Make sure not to clone from the building area constantly, because that destroys the whole purpose of this. Make sure you clone it every so often; maybe every day-night cycle?

Comment: If you want to know how to do this in more depth, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. However, what you are telling me here is in sort of one my failed project (it required the /testforblocks command you can check the question here:http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262125/testforblocks-system-problem )

Comment: @Kimatuy Ah, I see. But you really shouldn't need `/testforblocks`. Since you should only "backup" the area every so often, that should create no lag. If you backed it up whenever someone places a block, then the two fields would be identical, including right after the player detonates TNT in that area. If both areas are destroyed, what's the point of having the backup?

Comment: Yeah, you're surely right. But what I want my system to do is to detect if there is a change in the area, and if yes, change it back. Of course, there will be an "edit mode" system, so that we can change the build. But when not on, the /testforblocks command should be able to know that he will have a different build to check. This is my question, or more my project question.

Comment: @Kimatuy Ah, I see. Please look at my comment on your other question, I might be able to help you there.